# Flushing all caches throws me error - PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error -1

Tags: debugging

i got problem clearing my caches, it throws me an error - PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error -1 from storage engine: TRUNCATE {cache_field} ; Array ( ) in cache. I use xampp for a local dev server. I've read about this issue here - https://www.drupal.org/node/2229013 , but none of the answers helps me. I use drupal 7.43.

Thanks in advance!